# Edit method for EmployeeStore (HashMap)

Tags: java, hashmap, edit

Hey my edit method is not running correctly.  I'll tell you step by step how it isn't supposed to work.
Step 1:  The user inputs a name such as Luis Suarez and then the searchByName method will search for this name in the Employee Store.
Step 2:The User will again input employee details and this time it will overwrite the employee they wish to edit.

I will now show you my code:

MainApp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//              Name:        Case 4: Edit.
//              Description: Choice 4 gives the user an option to edit the employee's in the store.
//                           This consists of changing the employee's name,id and e-mail address.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Edit");
                Employee employeeEdit = MenuMethods.userInputByName();
                Store.searchByName(employeeEdit.getEmployeeName());
                if (employeeEdit != null) 
                {
                    employeeEdit.setEmployeeName("Joe");
                    employeeEdit.setEmployeeId(1);
                    employeeEdit.setEmployeeEmail("webmail.com");
                    Store.edit(employeeEdit);
                }
                break;
```

UserInputByName

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:        userInputByName.
//  Description: This method is used in the MainApp to give the user capability to search by name.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static Employee userInputByName() 
    {
        // String temp is for some reason needed. If it is not included
        // The code will not execute properly.
        String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
        Employee e = null;
        System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
        String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();

        return e = new Employee(employeeName);

    }
```

Edit

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: Edit.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void edit(Employee employee) 
    {
        map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
    }
```

Employee

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Employee class.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class Employee
{
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Variables to be used in the employee store.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private String employeeName;
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeEmail;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:        Constructors.
//  Description:
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Employee(String employeeName, int employeeId, String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Overloading the constructor for the use with userInputByName method.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Employee(String employeeName) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:   Getters.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String getEmployeeEmail() 
    {
        return employeeEmail;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() 
    {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public int getEmployeeId() 
    {
        return employeeId;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:   Setters.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setEmployeeEmail(String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId)
    {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:   toString.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "\t\t\tEmployee\n" +
                "********************************************************************\n"+
                "Employee Name: "+ employeeName +"\n"+ 
                "Employee Id: " + employeeId +"\n"+  
                "Employee Email: " + employeeEmail;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

SearchByName

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: Search by Name.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Employee searchByName(String employeeName)
    {
        Employee employee = map.get(employeeName);
        System.out.println(employee);
        return employee;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Could you post the implementation of `searchByName` method? Moreover if this method finds the object why are you hardcoding values before editing?

Comment: I edited my code with the searchByName method.  The values where hardcoded because i was testing the individual methods to work with the edit.

Comment: it seems that the value set in `employeeEdit.setEmployeeName(<value>);` forces the map not to find the `Employee` object and insert a new one. Printout the contents of this value before setting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this small demo :

```
HashMap<String, Employee> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Pendo826", new Employee("Pendo826", 1, "Pendo826@gmail.com"));

Employee e = map.get("Pendo826"); // get emp instance by name
e.setEmployeeName("Pendo"); // emp name of that instance edited 
System.out.println(map.get("Pendo826").getEmployeeName()); // name is changed within map
```

so simply your **case 5** :

```
System.out.println("Edit");
Employee employeeEdit = MenuMethods.userInputByName();
Employee e = Store.searchByName(employeeEdit.getEmployeeName());
if (e != null) 
{
  e.setEmployeeName("Joe");
  e.setEmployeeId(1);
  e.setEmployeeEmail("webmail.com");
  // Store.edit(employeeEdit); // no need as you already have made changes to reference e
}
break;
```

after that if you **view all** you will have the changes

Comment: lol sorry i had no internet yesterday.  So i came into the library now.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Store operates the employees by their name you should not change employee's name when you call edit.

1. If you call edit providing an employee with the name which is not stored yet - the new employee is inserted.
2. If you call edit providing an employee with name already stored - the emplyee with this name is being updated.